# load json from dict python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to convert a dictionary object into json, but unable to do so. I tried json.load(), json.loads() but it gives me following error:

```
File "lean.py", line 252, in createJSON
return json.loads(jsonElementDict)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

When I print dictionary object, it's as follows:

```
{
'city': 'Pittsburgh',
'state': 'Pennsylvania',
'gross_floor_area': '',
'energyData': [
 {
  'cdd': '0.0', 
  'reading': '80.8', 
  'monthYear': 'Nov-2014'
 }, 
 {
  'cdd': '0.0',
  'reading': '300000.0', 
  'monthYear': 'Nov-2014'
 }
]
}`
```

Code:

```
outputJSON = json.loads(jsonElementDict)
print outputJSON.json['city']
```

Comment: `loads` is parsing a JSON string into Python objects. `dumps` is encoding Python objects into a JSON string. And you seem to be starting from a dict (Python object), then trying something JSONy, and then accessing the result again as a dict - so I am very confused as to which direction you actually need.

Comment: I created a dict object which I need to send to another program which can read that object as JSON response. So I am trying to convert dict into JSON then trying to access elements of created JSON object to check if it correctly coded

Comment: JSON is a string, it doesn't have elements, only characters and substrings. There is no such thing in the Python world as a JSON object (except as a name for the way a dict is represented in JSON). If you want to access `'city'` element of a dict that is encoded in JSON, you first need to decode it (using `json.loads`), which will reconstruct the original dict (as much as possible), then access *its* `'city'` element.